# Is there a way to call $onInit function again in another method?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, grid, ngoninit

The problem I am using two different grids both are calling the same controller and grid Component. And I want to show/unshow a checkbox in one gird based on a Condition. Since the gridOptions are loaded while initiating OnInit Method I am not able to change the enableRowSelection method on click of another grid.

I tried the code shown below but the registerAction did not get called though I call the callOnInitFunction again.

```
this.callOnInitFunction = function(){
              this.isSelected= function isSelected() 
                  {
                      if(flag)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }
                      else
                          return false;
                  };

                  this.gridOptions = {
                      enableRowSelection: this.isSelected(),
                      enableSelectAll: this.isSelected()
                      //other gridoption codes goes here the I am registering the grid
                    data: [],
                      registerAction: function ($scope, gridApi) {
                          gridService.registerGrid('gridName', gridApi);          
                      }
                }
         
   };
//then I am calling this function in onInit and again in the update Method
this.$onInit = function() {
                 this.callOnInitFunction();
};
```

I even tried to put the $onInit Function in separate Method like below and call the method again but got compilation error that time.

```
  this.callOnInitFunction = function(){
                this.$onInit = function();
             };
```

Can anyone please guide me on this.Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```js
this.$onInit = this.callOnInitFunction;
```

Or, if the function become inaccessible after the assignment, you can try defining the function globally...

```js
function start() { /* ... */ }
```

...and assigning it to `this.callOnInitFunction`:

```js
this.callOnInitFunction = start;
```

Then you can call `start()` in other places.

Comment: If I call like this the everything is get called except  gridService.registerGrid('gridName', gridApi);  This has to be called right to reset the grid again with new data

Comment: I'm sorry. What is the everything?

Comment: for example enableRowSelection: this.isSelected() gets called and other gridValues has been set but this register function is not getting called  where we are setting the gridApi   ->                   
                    registerAction: function ($scope, gridApi) {
                          gridService.registerGrid('gridName', gridApi);          
                      }